# Can user "input" an object's attribute, so it uses it to call a method of this specific object?

Tags: python

Here's a working code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class c: 
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name 
        self.colour = colour
     
    def speak(self):
        print ("You're a " + self.name)
                 
obj1 = c('table', 'red')
obj2 = c('chair', 'blue')


ask = input("Enter a colour and I'll tell you which object you are > ")

if ask == obj1.colour:
    obj1.speak()
elif ask == obj2.colour:
    obj2.speak()
```

If I want to make this same "game stuff" with lots of objects, guess I have to add some "`if` statement" for each new object, like this:

```
elif ask == obj3.colour:
    obj3.speak()
elif ask == obj4.colour:
    obj4.speak()
elif ask == obj5.colour:
    obj5.speak()
```

but instead of having this uncool long "`if` list", is there any kind of short line code/function that would act like:

```
ask.speak()
```

In other words: Let the user "input" an object's attribute, so Python recognizes the object to which it belongs, and then Python calls a specific method for this object.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Are all the `obj{}` objects in any sort of data structure?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a code I'm trying to buid.. No data structure, but as suggested above, I'll try some list stuff...

Comment: How are all the objects being created/stored, then?

Comment: Actually objects are sounds that I play through Pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

You want a build a map of colors to objects with that color:

```
obj1 = c('table', 'red')
obj2 = c('chair', 'blue')
colour2object = {
  'red': obj1,
  'blue': obj2
}


ask = input("Enter a colour and I'll tell you wich object you are > ")

if ask in color2object:
    color2object[ask].speak()
else:
    print(f"No object with color {ask}")
```

Such a map can be populated as each instance is created.

```
class c:
    colour2object = {}

    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name 
        self.colour = colour
        self.color2object[colour] = self 

    def speak(self):
        print ("You're a " + self.name)

obj1 = c('table', 'red')
obj2 = c('chair', 'blue')

ask = input(...)
if ask in c.color2object:
    c.color2object[ask].speak()
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try this soon and then I'lllet you know!

Answer (score 0):

Your basic limitation here is that there is no defined container or structure that groups all of your objects together.

You could accomplish this pretty easily by storing all of your objects in a list and iterating through the list to find the matching color, like so:

```
objects = [
    c('table', 'red')
    c('chair', 'blue')
    ...
]

ask = input("Enter a colour and I'll tell you wich object you are > ")

for object in objects:
    if object.colour == ask:
        object.speak()
```

There are some notes for how the above implementation will function--namely, the loop will iterate through every object in the list and allow all objects that match the input color to call the `speak` method. If you'd prefer to stop looping through as soon as you've found the first object that matches the input color, you can add a `break` instruction immediately following the `speak` invocation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try this soon and then I'lllet you know!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification to your current solution would be to use a list and a for loop:

```
objlist = []
obj1 = c('table', 'red')
objlist.append(obj1)
obj2 = c('chair', 'blue')
objlist.append(obj2)
# or
objlist = [
    c('table', 'red'),
    c('chair', 'blue'),
]


ask = input("Enter a colour and I'll tell you wich object you are > ")

for obj in objlist:
    if ask == obj.colour:
        obj.speak()
        break
```

Another approach you could take is to use a dictionary

```
objlist = [
    c('table', 'red'),
    c('chair', 'blue'),
]
objmap = {v.colour: v for v in objlist}

ask = input("Enter a colour and I'll tell you wich object you are > ")

obj = objmap[ask]
obj.speak()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try this soon and then I'lllet you know!

Comment: List approach is simple - but inefficient. Not that it matters in that case, but list search is O(n) - dictionary lookup is O(1).